# Trying to understand closures (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

```
function myFunc(inputFunc){
  var called = false;
  return function() {
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      var storedResult = inputFunc();
      return storedResult;
    }
    else
      return storedResult;
    };
}
```

In the above code, I don't understand what purpose it serves to have the if-else statement returned in a function. Wouldn't it be the same effect if I just had the following instead?

```
function myFunc(inputFunc){
  var called = false;
  if (!called) {
    called = true;
    var storedResult = inputFunc();
    return storedResult;
  }
  else
    return storedResult;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

> Wouldn't it be the same...

Not really, the outer function returns a function, enclosing the called variable in it's scope so it doesn't change in later calls
Here's how the first code snippet would work

```
var instance = inputFunc();

var storedResult = instance(); // returns the result

var runItAgain = instance(); // probably returns `undefined`
```

Your second version wouldn't do any of that, it would just be

```
var storedResult = inputFunc(); // result

var runItAgain = inputFunc(); // result again, the "called" variable is always false
```

In other words, the first version returns the result once, and only once, here's a snippet

```js
function myFunc(inputFunc) {
    var called = false;
    return function() {
        if (!called) {
            called = true;
            var storedResult = inputFunc();
            return storedResult;
        } else
            return storedResult;
    };
}

var instance = myFunc(function() {
 return 'result';
});

var log = [];

log.push( instance() ); // result
log.push( instance() ); // undefined
log.push( instance() ); // undefined
log.push( instance() ); // undefined

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(log, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: The first code snippet is example of **Singleton pattern**

Comment: @Tushar - yes, it's a sort of Singleton, where the outer function creates a single instance with a "static" `called` variable that can be used by the inner function